# How to combine more than 2 arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach ($_GET['first_name'] as $first_name) {
   echo $first_name . '<br>';
}

foreach ($_GET['surname'] as $surname) {
   echo $surname . '<br>';
} 

foreach ($_GET['age'] as $age) {
   echo $age . '<br>';
} 

foreach ($_GET['gender'] as $gender) {
   echo $gender . '<br>';
}
```

The code above returns:

> All firstnames
>
> All surnames
>
> All ages
>
> All genders

I want it to look like this:

> Firstname Surname
>
> Age
>
> Gender
>
> ...
>
> [next person]

I have tried to resolve it this way:

```
$names = array_combine($_GET['first_name'], $_GET['surname']);
foreach($names as $firstname => $surname) {
    echo $firstname . ' ' . $surname . '<br>';
}
```

This would fix my problem for firstname and surname but I still wouldn't know how to handle the other arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your desired output:

```
foreach ($_GET['first_name'] as $id => $key) {

    echo $_GET['first_name'][$id]." ".$_GET['surname'][$id]." ".$_GET['age'][$id]." ".$_GET['gender'][$id]."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just run a loop with an incrementing variable and use that to specify the index of the arrays in each iteration.

Like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_GET['first_name']);$i++) {
    echo $_GET['first_name'][$i] . ' ' . $_GET['surname'][$i] . '<br>';
    //...etc
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but there is missing ) for count function Upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
array_merge($array1, $array2)
```

Found on: http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php